# How to put multiple ranges in change event

Tags: vba, excel

I need to check several cells before the macro is triggered by the change event.

This is the code

```
Private Sub CBbox_Change()

If Range("E13:E20") = vbNullString Then

Call Macro

End if

End Sub
```

The problem is I can only put a single range like this.

```
If Range("E13") = vbNullString Then
```

Comment: `and` in the `if` may help

Comment: Are you checking whether all of them are blank or any of them?

Comment: yes,I am checking for all of them are blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `WorksheetFunction.CountA` Function, there's no need to use a `For` loop.

You can read more about is on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838049.aspx)

```
Private Sub CBbox_Change()

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("E13:E20")) = 0 Then
    Call Macro
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thank you for sharing. New knowledge for me

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
Private Sub CBbox_Change()
   Status = False
   For Each Cell In Range("E13:E20")
       If Cell <> vbNullString Then
           Status = False
           Exit For
       End If
       Status = True
   Next Cell
   If Status Then
       Call Macro
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This way works, but then it will take longer time. Is there any other way?

Comment: You should basically check each cell if they are empty or not. There is no logical way to check all of them at the same time. WorksheetFunction.CountBlank() is a builtin function, which also iterates through each cell and it does not exit from loop anytime. This code exits loop immediately once it finds a non-empty cell. So it is actually shorter than it seems.

Comment: you are saying that there is no other way than check each of the cell?

Comment: Yes, you need to loop through cells somehow. One liner functions also loop to extract what you need. Have you tried this code and found it inefficient? or do you have any problem implementing it to your code?

Comment: @HappyForever you might want to read about `WorksheetFunction.CountA` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838049.aspx

Comment: I tried this code and it works fine, however it is less efficient because it will slow the file.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
Private Sub CBbox_Change()

Dim r As Range

Set r = Range("E13:E20")

If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(r) = r.Count Then
    Call Macro
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @SJR since you love "new" stuff, read about `WorksheetFunction.CountA` here :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838049.aspx

Comment: @ShaiRado - thanks. Am I missing something - is this a more efficient method than CountBlank, I had wondered? I have always heard that Excel functions are more efficient than VBA, but judging by Happy Forever's comment above this is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @nx170 - for future reference, "does not work" is the least helpful response imaginable. Explain why etc.